# Hardcode IPEndpoint gives Exception using ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, delegates, httpwebrequest

I am trying to Bind my Outbound IP for my webRequest

```
HttpWebRequest reqhttp = (HttpWebRequest)req;
reqhttp.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new System.Net.BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
reqhttp.Credentials = null;
reqhttp.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.None;
reqhttp.Method = "POST";
reqhttp.ContentLength = send.Length;
reqhttp.ContentType = "text/xml";

Stream dataStream = reqhttp.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
dataStream.Close();

 public delegate IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount);

    private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("111.111.11.11"), 0); //bind to a specific ip address on your server
    }
```

for some reason when i do this, it is throwing an error

if fails to execute this line

```
Stream dataStream = reqhttp.GetRequestStream();
```

**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

i don't understand what is wrong in here.

Can any one help to understand whats wrong in this code and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The GetRequestStream() method will first trigger BindIPEndPointDelegat, then it will try to connect to the remote server. If you bind to a local end point that does not exists, or the remote server is unavailable, you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have handled this differently. Will check your suggestion later.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myIP);
request.Proxy = myProxy;
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(myIP), myProxy);
sp.BindIpEndPointDelegate = new BindIpEndPoint(BindIpEndPointCallback);
HttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```